# Poor Performance with OpenCV 2.4.8 face detection

Tags: java, c++, opencv, face-detection

I installed the OpenCV 2.4.8 Java API to play with the face detection example that is given in the [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html#copy-the-opencv-jar-and-write-a-simple-application).

In the example, `lbpcascade_frontalface.xml` -which is a  `CascadeClassifier`- works OK in detecting the female face image (`lena.png`) that they provide. However, when I tried it on this random [image](http://www.standishstreetdental.co.uk/images/content/full-size/full-team.jpg) from the web, the classifier produced the following image, missing 4 obvious(!) faces:

[image]

I am quite disappointed because I expected this (with the clear contrasts) to be a very easy image for detecting faces.

**1)** Coding in Java, is it possible to improve this classifier to detect all faces in this picture? Or do I need C++ for this?

**2)** I looked at [OpenCV's `CascadeClassification` web page](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html) and saw taht it is possible to train your own classifier. But the instructions are in C++. Has anyone done this using Java or is it only doable in C++?

Comment: try to use other cascades, like lbpcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have saved your image and this c++ code finds the missing 4 faces as well as all the others (note the different Haar cascade and the minimum size):[image]

```
    Mat im1 = imread("JuVIA.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    vector<Rect> faces;
    CascadeClassifier cascade( "C:/local/opencv249/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml" );
    cascade.detectMultiScale( im1, faces, 1.1, 2, 0| CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

    for( vector<Rect>::const_iterator r = faces.begin(); r != faces.end(); r++ )
        cv::rectangle( im1, *r, CV_RGB(255,0,0) );

    imshow("in", im1);
    imwrite( "miss4.png", im1);
    waitKey();
```

Answer (score 3):

The training is not related to any programming language.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html

You need only to use two already written programs included in the opencv library: **createsamples** and **traincascade**. You can use Haar and LBP features too, but the Haar features are slightly better for face detection. (And by the way: don't use **haartraining**).

Comment: Thanks, why do you advise against using haarttraining?  I know that `opencv_traincascade` has replaced `opencv_haartraining` since some version 2.X so the latter is deprecated. ALso I hear that `opencv_haartraining`is too slow. Do you know of any other undesirable features of haartraining?

Comment: First: Because the "haartraining" is not supported any more, you will find very few help about using it. Second: Why use more programs, if you can use only one (If you want to change the type of the features but not the training data, you have to reset only the corresponding parameter).

Answer (score 1):

It is because the faceDetector the tutorial chose to use is lbpcascade_frontalface.xml which is not good enough, at least couldn't detect all the faces in the picture you used.

You may change to use haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml under opencv-2.4.8\sources\data\haarcascades folder. Then all faces would be detected.

Here following is the result:[image], more details please refer to:http://www.pkuaas.org/?uid-1140-action-viewspace-itemid-3224